# Bayesian Probability solving

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

[image]

The above diagram is the Bayesian Network.
I want to find P(M=t|A=t && E=f)

I have followed the follwoing steps.
 P(M=t|A=t && E=f) = P(M=t && A=t && E=f)/ P(A=t && E=f)

P(M=t && A=t && E=f)= P(M=t|A=t) *P(A=t|E=f && B=t) *P(E=f) *P(B=t)+ P(M=t|A=t) *P(A=t|E=f && B=f) *P(E=f) *P(B=f)

Now to calculate P(A=t && E=f),

I have followed-

P(A=t && E=f)= P(A=t|E=f)*P(E=f)

Now to calculate P(A=t|E=f),

P(A=t|E=f)=P(A=t|E=f && B=t)*P(B=t)+ P(A=t|E=f && B=f)*P(B=f)

Am I correct? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $M$ and $E$ are conditionally independent given A. Thus, the probability you are looking for is already given in your diagram:

$$P(M=t|A=t \wedge E=f)\,\,=\,\,P(M=t|A=t)$$

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case, I would not need this calculations. Straight forward answer 0.70.

Comment: Exactly, you do not need any calculations.

Comment: can we derive P(B|E) and P(B) for a fixed P(E) from this though both P(B) and P(E) are independent from each other?